# Copying object with const members to a non const object

Tags: c++

I have the following data container:

```
struct Node
{
    explicit Node(const std::vector<Data>& _data, const Value& _value): data(_data), value(_value)
    {
    }

    const std::vector<Data> data;
    const Value value;
};
```

I wish to write a mock along these lines:

```
class MockVisitor: public IVisitor
{
public:
    virtual void operator()(const Node& _node)
    {
        node = _node;
    }

    Node node;
};
```

However, I'm getting the error:

```
error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'Node'.
```

I'm presuming this is because I can only assign to a const Node. Is there anyway for my to cast away this error? Remember this is only a mock class. I'm simply trying to record the value passed into operator()() so I can check it in my unit test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the member variables `data` and `value` are declared as constant, the `operator=` is deleted. This is the reason you can not use it, hence the compilation error.

This should work :

```
class MockVisitor: public IVisitor
{
public:
    virtual void operator()(const Node& _node)
    {
        node.reset( new Node( _node ) );
    }

    std::unique_ptr< Node > node;
};
```

Comment: Very nice! I will use boost::shared_ptr instead since I'm not using C++11.

Answer (score 0):

Your Node class is immutable. It makes no sense to perform this action, since you are attempting to alter the value of the Node you already have in the MockVisitor. If you want to do this consider `boost::optional<Node>`.